# Random message using node.js

Tags: node.js

so i  want to let my bot choose from multiple messages when someone sends prefix + random but everytime i test it it says "0" and i dont know why. This is what i have already.

```
client.on('message', message =>{
  const member = message.guild.member
  if(message.content === prefix + 'random'){
    message.channel.send('random1' | 'random2' | 'random3')
  }

});
```

i also have tried doing "," instead of "|" but then it only sends random1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to send a random string, you cannot use `OR` operator (which is `||` btw...).

You have to do something like:

```
const randomStrings = ['random1', 'random2', 'random3'];
const getRandomInt = (max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * max);

client.on('message', (message) => {
  const member = message.guild.member;
  if (message.content === prefix + 'random') {
    message.channel.send(randomStrings[getRandomInt(randomStrings.length)]);
  }
});
```

Comment: litterly Thanks! Im doing this for a week now so everytime i have something new im so happy! This means much to me THANKS!!

Comment: I tried making two, so one with like prefix+ random and one with prefix + other but as soon as i add the other command it gets an error it says something with identifyer and i dont know how to fix it

Comment: Please open another question, I can't help you here

Comment: oke imma do it rn